# Hamiltonian Diffeomorphism

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I need to study Hamiltonian diffeomorphism, their definition and structure as a group. 
Could someone give me a bibliography suggestion other than Hofer Zehnder book?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The book introduction to symplectic topology by Dusa McDuff has a chapther (chapter 10 - the group of symplectomorphism) that has all the basic information for a first study.